# Terraform deletes Azure resources in subsequent 'apply' without any config change

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

I was trying to test the scenario of handling external changes to existing resources and then syncing my HCL config to the current state in the next apply. I could achieve that using 'taint' for the modified resource, but TF deleted other resources which were deployed during the first 'apply'. Here is the module code for a VNet with 3 subnets(prod,dmz and app) and 3 NSGs associated. And I tested with modifying one of the NSGs but TF deleted all of the subnets-

VNET-

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "BP-VNet" {

name = var.Vnetname
location = var.location
resource_group_name = var.rgname
address_space = var.vnetaddress
subnet {
    name = "GatewaySubnet"
    address_prefix = "10.0.10.0/27"
}
```

}

Subnet -

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
count = var.subnetcount
name = "snet-prod-${lookup(var.snettype, count.index, "default")}-001"
address_prefixes = ["10.0.${count.index+1}.0/24"]
resource_group_name = var.rgname
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.BP-VNet.name
```

}

NSGs-

```
    resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsgs" {
count = var.subnetcount
name = "nsg-prod-${lookup(var.snettype, count.index, "default")}"
resource_group_name = var.rgname
location = var.location
--------
}
```

BastionSubnet-

```
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "bastionsubnet" {
  name = "AzureBastionSubnet"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.BP-VNet.name
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  address_prefixes = [ "10.0.5.0/27" ]
}
```

The end result of second apply is -

[image]

With just Gateway subnet. It should not have deleted rest of the 4 subnets. Why is this happening?

Comment: About "I tested with modifying one of the NSGs", What's the specific process that you did?

Comment: Changed the priority of one of the inbound rules. After second apply, it was reverted back to the value mentioned in the HCL config.

Comment: Terraform run apply based on a template code from the last terraform.tfstate file. Have you checked the terraform.tfstate file before you re-run apply?

Comment: Yes. In the state file, I could see all the resources as expected

Comment: Would it be okay if I send you the zipped up module files to you - statefile, variables, and main? @NancyXiong

Comment: I think I have reproduced your issue. Did you change the priority of one of the inbound rules in the NSG that using count, then you taint that nsg, then run terraform apply?

Comment: @NancyXiong - Exactly yes!

Comment: @NancyXiong - Did you get a chance to look into this ?

Comment: What is the purpose you use the taint?

Comment: @CharlesXu- I was testing to see how can I bring back the externally modified resource back to its original state as mentioned in HCL config by redeploying

Comment: Can you share the whole Terraform code and the commands you use to taint the changed resource?

Comment: @CharlesXu- Here is the zipped code - https://demosg1199.blob.core.windows.net/tf-files/VNet-3Subnets-3NSGs.zip. Command I used is- terraform taint azurerm_network_security_group.nsgs[2]

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution may confuse you. You can separate the `GatewaySubnet` from the `azurerm_virtual_network` block into an `azurerm_subnet` block. The code looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "gateway" {
  name = "GatewaySubnet"
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.BP-VNet.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.10.0/27"]
}
```

I don't know the certain reason, but it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I tested this myself last weekend and it did help in not deleting the resources in subsequent apply. But my major concern was to understand the reason as mentioned in my question, if I am changing resources created from loops or along with parent resource.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava The loop does not matter. And you can also put all the subnets in the parent resource, the VNet resource. There is a guess that when it applies the second time, it will refresh all the resources state, and the subnet is not an individual resource, it's a sub resource of the VNet. So it only refreshes the VNet and ignores the subnets block. Not sure, but it's a possible reason. I didn't find any document that explains the reason.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava Any updates? Do you solve the issue?